# Firebase data structure RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display the module list in a RecyclerView. When the user clicks the module designation, I want it to show the list of objects from this module

I structured the base from a [Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0yR5.png)

The problem is that I can't the list of module designation

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Module, ModulesViewHolder>(Module.class, R.layout.item_module,
```

//                ModulesViewHolder.class, mFirebase.child("MODULES"))

and that my ModulesViewHolder

```
public class ModulesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public ModulesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        TextView tv_designation = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_module_name);
        tv_designation.setText(designation);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've included a link to picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.